# How do you resolve special folders in path strings in PowerShell?

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line, path

In the Windows Command Prompt, special folders are resolved like so:

[image: Command Prompt showing special folder resolution]

However, in powershell, these folders do not seem to be resolved:

[image: PowerShell Prompt showing %temp% being echoed literally]

Consider the string:

```
$myfile = "%temp%\\myfolder\\myfile.txt"
```

How can I use this as an argument to PowerShell functions (eg: `Remove-Item`), and have PowerShell correctly resolve the special folders, as opposed to taking it literally and prepending the current working directory?

### Edit:

I am working with strings using standard windows path notation coming from external configuration files, for example:

config.json:

```
{
    "some_file": "%TEMP%\\folder\\file.txt"
}
```

myscript.ps1:

```
$config = Get-Content -Raw -Path "config.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
Remove-Item -path $config.some_file -Force
```

Note: as any of the [Windows special folders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder) can appear in these strings, I'd rather avoid horrible find-replace hacks like this

```
$config.some_file = $config.some_file -replace '%TEMP%' $env:temp
```

Comment: well, you can create your own function to parse those, and convert them to values, I don't think there's anything else you can do (apart from your hack)

Comment: -replace '%(.*)%', '$env:$1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind some performance issues

`$resolvedPathInABitHackyWay = (cmd /c echo "%TEMP%\\folder\\file.txt")`

This will actually give you %TEMP% resolved by cmd itself.

Comment: You beauty!  This works perfectly, and performance is not an issue in my case (yet).

Comment: you call `$config.some_file = $config.some_file -replace '%TEMP%' $env:temp` a hack, but this is fine? madness @AlexMcMillan

Comment: @4c74356b41 It sure is!  The first requires me to maintain a list of all possible special folders (eg: `%TEMP%`, `%PROGRAMFILES%`, `%APPDATA%` etc) and iterate them every time; the latter is a tidy one-liner that'll resolve them all.

Comment: no, you can use regex from the comments, that will convert anything into powershell variable, so `%appdata%` becomes `$env:appdata`, `%temp%` becomes `$env:temp` and so on, would be much cleaner. you can also use regex to take care of `\\`

Comment: Downvoting my question because you believe I selected the wrong answer is petty.  This solution worked for me.  Bye

Answer (score 2):

You can expand it to a full path using:

```
[System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%TEMP%\\myfolder\\myfile.txt")

c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\\myfolder\\myfile.txt
```

Double-backslash `\\` isn't a PowerShell thing either, `\` is not a special character in a PowerShell string - but double backslashes in a path do seem to work.

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can grab all env variables from the `env:\` drive and use that to construct a succinct regex pattern for your find-replace operation, then use the `Regex.Replace()` method with a match evaluator:

```
$vars = Get-ChildItem env:\ |ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_.Name)}
$find  = "%(?:$($envNames -join '|'))%"
[regex]::Replace($config.some_file, $find, {param([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]$found) return (Get-Item "env:\$($found.Groups[1])").Value},'IgnoreCase')
```